# Workarounds for inheritance limits in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, inheritance

we are planning to restructure an existing database, which has grown in an not-so-logical way.
My database should model the following situation:

- we have many pieces of hardware, of different types. For some types, a few, generic fields are enough; for other types, we need a lot of specific fields;
- we have several "installations" of our final product around the world;
- installations are made by putting together pieces of hardware

At first, I thought Postgres inheritance was the ideal solution for this task.
Let's say:

```
-- hardware is for generic hardware
CREATE TABLE hardware
(
    id_hardware serial NOT NULL,
    id_hardware_model integer not null, -- points to a table with hardware models
    description character varying(255) not null,
    -- etc
    -- primary key, foreign keys, etc
);

-- let's suppose we need many additional fields for solar panels;
-- solar_panel inherits from hardware
CREATE TABLE solar_panel
(
    max_power_production_w integer,
    panel_area_cm2 double precision,
    -- etc
) INHERITS (hardware);

-- our installations
CREATE TABLE installation
(
    id_installation serial NOT NULL,
    id_nation integer,
    id_owner integer,
    -- latitude, longitude, etc
    -- primary key, foreign key, etc
);

-- the link between hardware and installations (time-dependent)
CREATE TABLE installation_hardware
(
    id_installation int NOT NULL,
    id_hardware int not null,
    start_date date not null,
    end_date date,
    -- primary key
    -- two foregn keys:
    CONSTRAINT ih_installation_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_installation) references installation(id_installation),
    CONSTRAINT ih_hardware_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_hardware) references hardware(id_hardware)
);
```

Then I discovered that inheritance in Postgres has some serious limitations. Quoting from the documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html) (it uses an example with "cities" as parent table and "capitals" as child table):

> If we declared cities.name to be UNIQUE or a PRIMARY KEY, this would not stop the capitals table from having rows with names duplicating rows in cities. And those duplicate rows would by default show up in queries from cities. In fact, by default capitals would have no unique constraint at all, and so could contain multiple rows with the same name. You could add a unique constraint to capitals, but this would not prevent duplication compared to cities.
> [...]
> Specifying that another table's column REFERENCES cities(name) would allow the other table to contain city names, but not capital names. There is no good workaround for this case.

Instead of giving up with inheritance, I thought maybe I could handle the situation in this way:

1. in installation_hardware, I do not create the foreign key pointing to hardware; instead, force the referential integrity by using trigger(s) on installation_hardware;
2. force uniqueness of id_hardware in "hardware" and all children tables by using triggers (of course, id_hardware will be normally generated by the sequence, but just to be on the safe side...);

I want to stress that the insert/update/delete operations on these table will be very lightweight (only a few operations per day, at worst), so I think there is no performance concern with triggers.

Does all this make sense? Can you suggest some improvements or alternatives?
Thank you.

Comment: I don't see why you should use inheritance in this case. Simple foreign keys could solve your problem as well

Comment: @FrankHeikens Using inheritance I can have a single installation_hardware relation, instead of one relation for each type of hardware; less tables, and simpler "joins". Also notice that I want to keep an history of these relations (see fields start_date and end_date in installation_hardware).

Comment: The fact that you're already running into problems, tells me that using inheritance is not simpler. Offtopic: The start_date/end_date can be done in a single column, using a tsrange data type

Comment: See [Don't Do This](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_table_inheritance).

Comment: So, we have inheritance, a beautiful and useful feature, which is discouraged even in the (almost) official documentation... very sad... anyway, I understand the reasons.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may interested, I've found these two good discussions on inheritance and databases:

[How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

https://typedb.com/blog/inheritance-and-polymorphism-where-the-cracks-in-sql-begin-to-show

They address the problem with standard SQL.

Comment: As this is not answering the question but only linking some additional resources it should rather be a comment. Once you earn enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you'll be able to [comment everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)